# Using URL or File (in ImageIO.read)

Tags: java, file, url, javax.imageio

I made an application that uses several images. I have 2 ways to run my app:
- press `run` in idea 
- make a fat jar file and run it from console `java -jar app.jar`

If I want to run it from `Idea` I have to use:

`BufferedImage backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(new File("res/field.png"));`

instead of

`BufferedImage backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("res/field.png"));`
<- that's what I have to use in jar file case

Why? I thought that they're about the same. Is there any universal way for my case?

Answer (score 2):

I always use:

```
BufferedImage backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("res/field.png"));
```

which works from both the IDE and from inside a jar. .getResource(...) returns an URL, either jar:// or file://

Just be aware, the path either starts with a / (in which case it is relative to the package root) or it is relative to the class package - if your class is com.example.Test, `/res/` refers to the folder com/example/Test/res/.

You can even use the static version - YourClassName.class.getResource(...) which allow you to easily reach other "branches" of your package tree (you can use reference is from classes located in different branches)

Comment: it works, but I have to store my images inside class folder... Is there any other way to use project root?

Comment: If your path starts with a slash the path is relative to the root of the source folder.Ie, if your package is com.something you can access files and folders at the same level as com/

Comment: I need to access root of the project which contains src, res and etc... I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: When you pack a jar, the Res folder is either not included or included at the same level as it was put directly under src/. if you want it to be accessible in a uniform way the standard is to keep it SRC/ so in both the jar and IDE the folder is in the same place

Comment: So.. I have to keep my `res` folder in `src` folder if I want it to be accessible in a uniform way? And there isn't any other way?

Comment: Basically yes - you should create the jar, unzip it with WinZip and see where the IDE puts the Res folder... and make sure your project has the same folder structure

Comment: can you please post a screenshot of the folder structure? maybe there is another way

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143878/java-image-loading-doesnt-show-up-in-jar

Comment: I posted a screenshot, but it didn't appear... As to project structure I don't want to change it, because I don't want to see `res` in my `src` ;) So... There is no uniform way... Anyway thank you all for help!

Comment: Well, in this case, there is a trick you can use - put a placeholder file somewhere in your src. Try to get that with getClass().getResource(). You get back a "file://..." or a "jar:file..." uri, which allows you to programmatically detect if you are running from inside a jar or from the IDE - then you can use a conditional statement to use one the two methods you are already using to load your resource in the appropriate way

Answer (score 1):

With `java.io`, the relative path is dependent on the current working directory. 
With getResource you must have that resource in the `classpath`.