# Java ImageIO.read(File vs URL)

Tags: java, swing, file, url, javax.imageio

According to the API, the Java's ImageIO `(javax.imageio.ImageIO)` provides several overloaded methods for the `.read()` method.

Two of those methods were:

```
ImageIO.read(File input) 
ImageIO.read(URL input)
```

The Oracle tutorial website uses the read from file method `ImageIO.read(File input)`. However I've seen many example coded by the programmers here prefer to use the URL approach `ImageIO.read(URL input)`.

**Exmaple:**

```
img = ImageIO.read(new File("myImage.png"));
                        vs
img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("images/myImage.png"));
```

**My question is:** If I am only coding for a Java Desktop app (and not a Java applet). Is there is significant advantage for using the URL approach over the other?

---

**Note**: There is a post with similar title in SO: [Using URL or File (in ImageIO.read)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231027/using-url-or-file-in-imageio-read)

But this question address specifically on IDE. But I am not asking based on any specific IDE, but generally is there any prominent advantage for one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ..is there any prominent advantage for one over the other?

An `URL` can refer to a place on the internet, a file on the user's local file system, or a resource inside a Jar file - an [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource).

A `File` can refer to a file on the user's local file system, and.. well, that is about it.

So, unless read/**write** access is required to the resource, I'd go with the URL since it is more versatile.

Comment: So the only advantage is versatility and maybe it is also safer to use the URL approach since it can also read embedded resources such as from the `JAR`. Am I right to say that?

Comment: *"So the only advantage is versatility.."*  How many advantages do you *want?*  One is enough to make me reach for the URL.  *"..and maybe it is safer.."*  I'd call it 'forward thinking'.  After all, if the app. becomes distributed (typically as a Jar).  The `File` will fail quite reliably.  Exactly as reliably as the `URL` will work.  So not so much 'safer' as 'not utterly  broken'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Can you also explain your last sentence `So, unless read/write access is required to the resource, I'd go with the URL since it is more versatile` When write access is needed, how is `File` approach better than the `URL` approach then?

Comment: We can't open an output stream to an `URL`, but we [**can** to a `File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html).. If the code needs write access, `URL` is not an option.

Comment: I like your answer, it was straight to the point and answered directly.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to keep your resources inside archive than keeping files in your file system. Suppose you want to distribute the `JAR` file. Then it will not work properly on other computers . Moreover one might delete those files by mistake . On the other hand `JAR` archives are meant to be uneditable . Better choice to keep inside JAR. If want to drop from internet , the story is different.